# When and how did the Japanese honorific system evolve?

Tags: japanese, evolution, formality

I know that languages, in general, can denote honorifics, especially with second person pronouns (T/V distinction, etc), and I imagine that the Japanese system of honorifics is probably an extension of that into other persons with more granularity. However, did the Japanese system evolve a thousand years ago? Two thousand? Are the honorifics derived from nouns or verbs or some other class of words?

Comment: The system of [Javanese politeness registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javanese_language#Registers) is even more complex than Japanese (but then of course Java is even more crowded than Japan).

Comment: Stating that Japanese has pronouns is already a [controversial statement](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/9016/does-japanese-have-pronouns).

Answer (score 5):

As a partial answer, [this dissertation](http://vsarpj.orinst.ox.ac.uk/files/russell.dissertation.pdf) by K. Russell reconstructs verbal morphology of proto-Japonic. Certain morphemes are reconstructed (ch. 4) at the level of proto-Japonic, but others are only reconstructed at a later level such as Old Japanese. The honorific morphemes *-as-, -imas-, -tamap-* is reconstructed to OJ. No honorific morphemes are reconstructed to proto-Japonic, although Ryukyuan languages have honorifics.